# "Seventeen days' notice" versus "seventeen day's notice"

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

> Even in those days, this was incredibly rude! Giving the President of your country only ***seventeen days'' notice*** before making a speech, especially as he wasn’t top of the bill, would be unthinkable today! So, the day arrived, and Everett, well prepared, displayed his oratorical skills in a speech which lasted over two hours. Lincoln, on the other hand, spoke for just over two minutes.
>   https://www.lingq.com/el/lesson/lesson-28-the-gettysburg-address-431424/

I guess there is a mistake in the above context. It should be *seventeen day's notice*, not *seventeen days notice*, but I am not sure. Am I right or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that it's a typo, but the corrected version is not what you think.

*Seventeen days* is a plural noun. Therefore, the possessive apostrophe goes after the *s*:

> seventeen days' notice

---

Only if it were a singular noun would the apostrophe go before an added *s*:

> one day's notice